# Recursion & Async function does not respect/wait for promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion, async-await, promise

### Situation:

I have a function which runs at the start of my code `load_content`:

```js
async function load_content() {
    console.log("I GOT HERE 1");
    await load_js_files("./cmds/","commands")
    console.log("I GOT HERE 2");
    await load_js_files("./events/","events");
}
```

This function calls `load_js_files` twice, `load_js_files` is a recursive function which calls itself for each directory in the specified directory, 'requiring' each file found and doing different things if `type = commands` or `type = events`.

The function `load_js_files` looks like:

```js
function load_js_files(dir,type){
    fs.readdir(dir, (e, files) => {
        if(e) console.error(e);

        let jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
        if(jsfiles.length <= 0){
            console.log(`No commands to load from ${dir}!`);
            return;
        }
        for(const file of files){
            if(fs.lstatSync(dir+file).isDirectory()){
                load_js_files(dir+file+"/",type)
            }
        }
        if(type === "commands"){
            console.log("\x1b[4m%s\x1b[0m",`Loading ${jsfiles.length} commands from ${dir} ...`);
            jsfiles.forEach((f,i) => {
                let command = require(`${dir}${f}`);
                console.log(`${i + 1}: ${f} loaded!`);
                bot.commands.set(command.info.name, command);
            });
        } else if (type === "events"){
            console.log("\x1b[4m%s\x1b[0m",`Loading ${jsfiles.length} events from ${dir} ...`);
            jsfiles.forEach((f,i) => {
                let event = require(`${dir}${f}`);
                console.log(`${i + 1}: ${f} loaded!`);
                let commands = [];
                for(const cmd of bot.commands){
                    if(cmd[1].data) commands.push(cmd[1].data.toJSON());
                }
                if(event.once){
                    bot.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, commands));
                } else {
                    bot.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, commands));
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log(log_Red,"FUNCTION 'load_js_files' CALLED WITH INCORRECT 'type'.")
        }
    });
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => resolve("DONE"));
}
```

I would expect in `load_content` that the events occur in this order:

1. console logs `I GOT HERE 1`
2. `load_js_files` occurs with `commands` parameter (granted I haven't solved recursion promises yet it should run once at least)
3. console logs `I GOT HERE 2`
4. `load_js_files` occurs again but with `events` parameter.

### Issue:

Upon running `load_js_files` requiring `type = event` the variable (`bot.commands`) is undefined. `bot.commands` is assigned values based in step 2 above, during the `load_js_files` call.

From what I can debug to, the initial function `load_content` does not respect (my understanding) of async/await, so I assume I am doing something incorrectly with promises.

In my console however the two `console.log` statements execute immidiatley & before the function is finished:

```
I GOT HERE 1
I GOT HERE 2
Loading 3 commands from ./cmds/ ...
1: createtables.js loaded!
2: ping.js loaded!
3: sqltest.js loaded!
Loading 1 events from ./events/ ...
1: ready.js loaded!
Loading 1 commands from ./cmds/settings/ ...
1: set.js loaded!
```

### What I've tried:

I've tried the code noted above, additionally I have tried wrapping the second run of `load_js_files` in a `.then()`, I've tried a callback function & I've also tried nesting Promises but run into issues as `load_js_files` is calling itself recursively.

I'm having a hard time understanding if these Promises are going to work with this type of recursion (all recursions of `load_js_files` **must** finish before the second `load_js_files` is called within `load_content`).

### Bonus points:

Bonus points if you can help me understand promises within a recursive function. I've read

- https://blog.scottlogic.com/2017/09/14/asynchronous-recursion.html
- https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3201-exploring-recursive-promises-in-javascript.htm
  and
- https://medium.com/@wrj111/recursive-promises-in-nodejs-769d0e4c0cf9

But it's not quite getting through.

### Attempt at implementing David's answer:

This results in error, I believe related to `fs.readdir(dir)` requiring a callback.

Error: `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined`

```js
async function load_js_files_async_test(dir,type){
    const files = fs.readdir(dir);
    for (const file of files) {
        const file_info = await lstat(dir + file);
        if(file_info.isDirectory()){
            await load_jsfiles_async_test(dir + file + "/", type);
        } else {
            console.log("Thanks David!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return new Promise((resolve,reject) => resolve("DONE"));` Its not waiting for anything. Like, it resolves immediately, what did you expect?

Comment: It's not strictly *recursive* because it's not calling itself.  A callback within it is calling it.  There's *a lot* of code here and you may want to reduce it to something smaller/simpler to get a handle on Promises first.  But take a look at [the Promises version(s)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreaddirpath-options) of what you appear to be using.  For example, if you `await readdir()` as a Promise and then iterate over its results and `await` recursive calls on those results, *that* is recursive and awaitable and doesn't need a hard-coded instant-resolve Promise at the end.

Comment: In general, for a function with lots of Promises and loops like this, you probably want to avoid the use of callback functions as much as possible.  They're clouding the overall operation and making the effort more confusing for you.  Use Promise-based file system operations, use normal loops instead of `forEach`, etc.

Comment: @tkausl, as the function is synchronous I believed this would send a resolved promise at the end (of the synchronous code).

Comment: @David in the function `load_js_files`, `load_js_files` calls itself - this is what I was referring to as recursion:

```js
for(const file of files){
            if(fs.lstatSync(dir+file).isDirectory()){
                load_js_files(dir+file+"/",type)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps I need to explore a less complex way of loading all the files from the directory + sub directory before working with the promise here?

Comment: @SirKhaoz: That's exactly the part that you're getting confused about.  `load_js_files` does not call `load_js_files`.  The callback function being passed to `fs.readdir` calls `load_js_files`.  And it does that after `load_js_files` has already returned, because JavaScript is single-threaded and asynchronous callbacks will be invoked after the current code finishes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The function

```
fs.readdir
```

Is a non blocking function which means that the code that you inserted there is not being 'awaited' to be done, you could try with `fs.readdirSync` and remove your `return new Promise()`.

Comment: This caused (without errors) the code to not execute, with or without the instant resolution promise.

Comment: Did you adapt the syntax corresponding to readdirSync? There are some changes to be done https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-readdirsync-method/

Comment: My bad, you're right. I missed some additional changes, I will re-code this, perhaps I can avoid promises all together on this!

Comment: Managed to adapt this (moved from async to sync handling of that portion of code) and it worked just fine. Sorry to whomever downvoted you, it was a good suggestion despite not being exactly what was asked in the first question.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, so kind! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

> does not respect/wait for promise

Sure it does.  This is the Promise it's awaiting:

```
new Promise((resolve,reject) => resolve("DONE"))
```

That Promise of course finishes *very quickly* (and synchronously) and then the code moves on to the next task.  But what isn't being awaited anywhere in the code is this asynchronous operation:

```
fs.readdir(dir, (e, files) => {
  //...
});
```

This call to `readdir` is an asynchronous operation, and as such that callback function won't be invoked until after the current thread finishes everything it's doing.  Which includes the "promises" being awaited (which don't do anything asynchronous) as well as the `console.log` statements and the next invocation of `load_js_files`.

Fortunately, Node provides [Promise-based versions](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreaddirpath-options) of these operations as well.

Simplifying the original code a bit, imagine instead this structure:

```
async function load_js_files(dir, type) {
  const files = await readdir(dir);
  for (const file of files) {
    const fileInfo = await lstat(dir + file);
    if(fileInfo.isDirectory()) {
      await load_js_files(dir + file + "/", type)
    }
  }
  // etc.
}
```

As you can see, this "reads" a lot more like synchronous operations.  The idea here is to remove the usage of callback functions, which are essentially causing you confusion and making "awaiting" much more difficult.  Now all of the logic in the `load_js_files` function is directly *in* the `load_js_files` function, not in other anonymous callback functions.  And that logic proceeds, step by step, awaiting each asynchronous operation.

Then you can `await` the calls to `load_js_files` as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answers David. I've updated my question to include an attempt at implementing this - as you say removing some of the bloat makes it easier to read, but with this implementation it's still asking for a call back function; error: `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined`

Comment: @SirKhaoz: Are you importing the promise-based file system functions or the regular ones?  The imports are a little different.

Comment: `const fs = require("fs")` will capture both no?

Comment: @SirKhaoz: It will not, no.  Take a look at the examples in the link provided.  For example: `import { readdir } from 'fs/promises';`